# React Native animation lags on iPhone X

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-sectionlist

Section lists seem to become laggy a few models into a navigation stack.

So Homepage (Section list is fine). Open Page 2 (Section list is starting to lag just a bit). Open page 3 (Section list is very laggy).

Transitions between these pages are the same. Main -> 2 is fine, 2 - 3 is slow

Orientation change is the same.

I'm not sure why this seems to only occur on iPhone X but is this a known problem? Is there a way around this?

Heres a snack project of the very laggy page 3

https://snack.expo.io/H14g80fXm

Comment: Have you tried running it in production mode?

Comment: @Filipe This is the TestFlight build which is a stand-alone app that’s default production I believe